# Rails has_many association: get virtual attribute of associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following two associations:

```
# models
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author, allow_destroy: true
  attr_accessor :foo_virtual_attr
end
```

Now I populate some records

```
author = Author.create(name: "John")
author.books.build(title: "book_1").save
author.books.build(title: "book_2").save
author.books.build(title: "book_3").save
```

That is the setup, here is the situation:

Let us say I have a form that is updating a specific `book`, say the `book` record with `title = "book_1"`. That form has `nested_fields_for` its associated `author`, so the form is updating the associated `author` too.

Before I call `update` in the `books_controller`, which will update the `book` and its associated `author`, I  set the book's virtual attribute of `foo_virtual_attr` to `true`.

Now when that `update` happens: I want that `author` (the one associated to the `book`) to be able to grab the virtual attribute that is set within the associated `book`.

- In other words, the `author` should be able to say: "Hey, I am being updated by ***this specific*** `book` that is associated to me, and here is the value for its virtual attribute of `foo_virtual_attribute`."

I do not want the `author` record to query the database for the `book` because then the `author` record will not know about the book's virtual attribute.  I could probably grab the virtual attribute by digging into the params hash, but that is not ideal.  I imagine that there has to be a way for the `author` to know which of its associated `books` is causing it to be updated.

Hopefully this makes sense.  I am not sure if this is possible...

Comment: Try ' self.book.virtual_attr' from before save of Author model

Comment: @Tachyons but `Author` has_many books.  How will it know to grab the appropriate book?

Comment: hello, why do you have `book` accept attributes for `author`? Have you considered passing a `book` to a method that will update an author

Comment: @Bohdan I am not sure I quite understand your question or your suggestion.  Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an answer to your question but I can't post comment to question due to lack of reputation that's why posting it as an answer

What if you maintain a virtual attribute in `Author` i.e. `last_updated_book`. Then you can query `author.last_updated_book.foo_virtual_attribute`